# First java program: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java

I am writing my first program in java. I am in grade 7. I cannot figure out why my "guess button" is not working. my debugger says

> "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException

My input string is `""`

```
public class GuessingGame extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField txtGuess;   // text field for the user's guess
    private int theNumber;             //the number we're trying to guess
    private JTextField textField;

    public void checkGuess() {  // method/function to check too high or too low
            // get the user's guess
            String guessText = txtGuess.getText();
            String message = "";    

            // check the user's guess for too low/too high
            int guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText);
            // too high 
            if (guess > theNumber)
            {
                message = guess + " was too high. Guess again!";
                lblOutput.setText(message);

            }
            // too low
            else if (guess < theNumber)
            {
                message = guess + " was too low. Guess again!";
                lblOutput.setText(message);
            }
            else 
            {
                 message = guess + " was right! You win! Let's play again! ";
                 lblOutput.setText(message);
                 newGame();
            }

    }

         public void newGame(){  // create a new random number  1..100

            theNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1); 

         }

         public GuessingGame() {
         getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        ...

        txtGuess = new JTextField();
        panel.add(txtGuess);
        txtGuess.setColumns(10);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(366, 18, 71, 22);
        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnGuess = new JButton("Guess!");
        btnGuess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                checkGuess();
            }
        });
        btnGuess.setBounds(195, 159, 97, 25);
        ...
    }
...
```

I have no idea what is causing the error.

Comment: How can you convert empty string into a number. Please put a check before conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest your code. You should switch-case or design patterns.

workaround :

```
        public void checkGuess() {  // method/function to check too high or too low
        // get the user's guess
        String guessText = txtGuess.getText();
        String message = "";   

        if(guessText.isEmpty()){
           return;
        }
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided, the only conclusion I can get is that you do not check the variable "guessText".

In the Integer.parseInt(string s) method, the characters in the string must all be decimal digits. @source docs.oracle

So:

```
if ( !guessText.isEmpty()){
  rest of the code
} else {
message = "The guess cannot be empty :(";
lblOutput.setText(message);
}
```

Hope this helped. If this did not work. I will need more input off the code.

Comment: I am following an online course and my code is exactly like the instructor's code. That is why i am struggling to find the problem. I get no other errors, other than the error above.  I have googled the error but none of the results that were given applies to my question... So I am not sure where else to look or to ask questions.

Comment: The error, java.lang.NumberFormatException, is almost 100% sure from a ParseInt so you should just verify if the input you are getting is an actual number or not. An easy solution  would be to debug the code and see what is the input of the ParseInt. In case you cannot debug just surround your code with an try catch and see the value where it breaks. In your case would be:  

public void checkGuess() { ...
try {
            int guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText); 
            (... rest of the code)
} catch (e){
   System.out.println(guessText)
}